# Can't delete Private Endpoints

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

I have multiple Private Endpoints configured in my Subscription, which I can't delete. Simply get a 'failed to delete' message with no further information.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the private endpoints, make sure that you have removed their dependencies in order.

Try this cmdlet to remove a private endpoint connection.

```
Remove-AzPrivateEndpointConnection -Name MyPrivateEndpointConnection1 -ResourceGroupName TestResourceGroup -ServiceName MyPrivateLinkServiceName
```

Use the `Get-AzPrivateLinkService` cmdlet to get the Private Endpoint connections and their states.

```
Get-AzPrivateLinkService -Name myPrivateLinkService -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup
```

You could read [Manage a Private Endpoint connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/manage-private-endpoint) for more details or let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Tried to remove dependencies in order, didn't work. Couldn't delete the Private Endpoint Connections on Key Vault, Storage Account etc.. Ended up deleting the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try these below steps:

1. Navigate to your subscription in the Azure portal
2. Go to Resource Provider on the left navigation bar
3. Select the Microsoft.RecoveryServices provider from the list of providers
4. Click Re-register. This might take a few minutes to take effect

After that, please try to delete the Private Endpoint again and see if it helps.

If this doesn't work, I would suggest reaching out to Azure Support to further troubleshoot this issue. Thank you!